# Stack Exchange still uses Wikipedia's Citation Needed text

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, wording, post-notices

Currently, the wording for the citation needed moderator notice is:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this **article** by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

"Article", to me, sounds wrong. On a Q&A site rather than an encyclopaedia should this not read:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this **post** by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

Or even specific for question/answer (though as the notice can be applied to both a little more work would be necessary to implement this).

---

[image: Image to prove I'm not tripping xD]

[Link to the notice applied to a post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/do-cows-produce-milk-excessively/1363#1363).

Comment: Um, is that not *Wikipedia's* "citation needed" notice? Where on SO is this used?

Comment: @Pekka that's exactly what I thought.  [Example Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/1363/69)

Comment: Hey, cool! When did that come up?

Comment: @Pekka: These tend to show up more on sites other than SO.  e.g., [gaming.se] is just fodder for people to make up guesses to questions with nothing to really back it up.  It's been around for months AFAIK.

Comment: @Pekka, they were requested by Skeptics.SE where answers must be referenced. [They are used there frequently](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed).

Comment: Is this something that a mod applies to a post, or is it based on heuristics/voting?

Comment: @Phoenix mods manually apply it :)

Comment: +1 I like your article

Comment: @Skliwz what have been fixed that you changed from no-repro to status-completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce this wording in the current version of our sites, and so I have resolved this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).